# django production server i18n urls not redirecting?

Tags: django

On my local server, when I go to the homepage by typing 127.0.0.1:8000 it automatically pushes me to /en/ like I want it to.

On my production server it drops me in '/' which gives me a 404 error. Oddly enough any of the link i click on in my 404 page which still has the site header will take me to the /en/ urls and then everything works fine.

Did I miss something here? Why isn't it redirecting me automatically?

EDIT: forgot to add the code...

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^forum/', include('djangobb_forum.urls', namespace='djangobb')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
)
```

EDIT: semi solved....

ok so after much trial and error I found that it was coming from having custom 404 and 500 templates, I have no clue why and I would really like to try and keep my custom templates... Any ideas?

Comment: How did you implement the redirect?

Comment: can't believe I forgot to add that, added to the main post...I believe that was all that was involved when I first implemented it

Comment: I think this problem is caused by the webserver configuration, rather than Django itself.

Comment: added my nginx settings

Comment: the problem is coming from custom 404 and 500 templates, but IDK why

Comment: If you implement a custom view, be sure it returns an `HttpResponseNotFound`

Comment: how would I redner my custom template with that line? HttpRNF(render())?

Comment: oh wait, it looks like it id finding the template anyway... IDK how that is possible but it is working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the custom 404 and 500 handler lines that the docs say to add to urls.py. I think I only needed these if I wanted some special behavior on a 404 and 500 past a custom template. I took out the views and the handlers in urls.py and left the 404.html and 500.html templates in the templates folder and everything works as I would want it to...

Comment: Wow, nice ! I had this error too. It was due to 404 template too. Thanks !